# Create a decentralized file server out of multiple desktops with Windows 7 OS

Tags: storage, cluster, p2p

I have a bunch of desktops with Windows 7 OS and some unused hard disk space on each one that I would like to connect together and use as a big file server that can be seen by all the desktops. I want to be able to access all the hard disks with just one IP. Redundancy is needed in case that some desktops are off.

we have a lot of Desktops in every department of our organization. maybe 50 desktop in each department. at least 70% of storage capacity of these desktops are free. in Linux we can use Tahoe_LAFS to aggregate these free spaces and make a distributed decentralized storage that supports redundancy too. but our desktops are in Windows OS

is this possible on Windows too?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Is there a particular reason you want to use multiple computers versus a single computer hosting multiple hard drives (including the possibility of using that one machine to host a RAID array)?

Comment: @Twisty Yes. we have a lot of Desktops in every department of our organization. maybe 50 desktop in each department. at least 70% of storage capacity of these desktops are free. in Linux we can use Tahoe to aggregate these free spaces and make a distributed decentralized storage that supports redundancy too. but our desktops are in Windows OS.